# Matplotlib ListedColormap: Several colorbars are returned instead of a unified one

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am mapping some data. This data consists of some discretized values. A map of this data should look like below:

[image]

But my code returns the following map:

[image]

My code that generates the second map is like the below:

```py
def discrete_mapping(*arguments):
       
    # some process is done to generate the data

    slices = [0.001] # setting the minimum value for each slice of the map

    for i,line in enumerate(lines):

        # some processes to generate other slices using a 'lines' list

        slices.append(0.999) # setting the maximum value 
        cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['green', 'cyan', 'yellow', 'orange','blue', 'linen','saddlebrown','salmon','darkkhaki'][:len(slices)-1])
        bounds = slices # this shows where should the slices be truncated
        norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N, clip=True)
    
    
    # some other process is done to generate values for the scatter plot 

    plt.imshow('# data first generated',  origin='lower', cmap=cmap)
    plt.scatter('# data related to scatter plot')
    cbar = plt.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap),extendfrac='auto',ticks=bounds,spacing='uniform')
    cbar.set_label('',labelpad=+2)
    plt.title('Discretized map of Index Overlay')
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8, 8)
```

At this moment, the map only shows two colors on the color bar. How can I make the color bar represent all colors generated on the map?

Comment: If you use a loop, remove `plt.colorbar` from the function and only call it after the loop

Comment: @mozway many thanks, but it didn't work! I removed it from the loop, it generated one single color bar that doesn't represent the actual colors.